# Habilitar e inhabilitar Radio Button en formularios web

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo dos `radio buttons` con formulario a llenar, y quisiera que al seleccionar uno el otro formulario quede inhabilitado. Ya he probado de todo y no le encuentro la vuelta.

¡Desde ya Gracias!!!!

Comment: Bienvenida, por favor lee [ask] y de paso checa el [tour], si pudieras agregar *todo* o parte de lo que has intentado, entonces sería mas fácil saber desde que punto ayudarte

Comment: Hola Romina, minimamente deberías mostrar que tienes hasta ahora o que intentaste hacer hasta ahora. Saludos

Comment: Hay una propiedad que se llama `readonly` se puede aplicar a los **input**, más no se si se puede a los **radio buttons**, debería también, ya que son campos de ingreso de información, aunque sean tipo `boolean`

Answer (score 1):

Con JavaScript lo puedes hacer con esta funcion

```
function desactiva(){
    document.nombreform.nombreboton.disabled=true;
    document.nombreform.nombreboton.disabled=true;
}
```

Comment: Gracias, pero se ve que algo me esta faltando porque no me funciona!!

Comment: Considera darte una vuelta por la sección de [answer], sería muy genial si editas tu aporte y agregas una explicación de modo que los demás comprendamos como esto soluciona el problema expuesto

Comment: El problema es que no veo su codigo entonces no puedo darle un consejo para su problema lo que he puesto ahi es un codigo generico para desactivar  Lo que se hace es diabled = true y disabled = false

Answer (score 1):

Jmmmmm, le has dado los mismos nombres a ambos radio button?

```html
Radio 1
<input type="radio" name="myFormRadio" />

Radio 2
<input type="radio" name="myFormRadio" />

Radio X
<input type="radio" name="myFormRadio" />
```

Si no le das el mismo nombre, no existe una referencia de que pertenezcan al mismo formulario y por tanto se comprobarán de forma independiente, como si no fueran dos opciones de la misma pregunta, por así decirlo.

Una vez hecho esto, ya puedes ponerle un evento en JavaScript que desactive todos los demás que no sean el seleccionado :

```js
var radios = document.formName.myFormRadio;

for (var i=0, i<radios.length; i++) {
  // aquí pones la condición que te interese para desactivarlos
  // y asocias este código a un evento de JavaScript
  radios[i].disabled = true;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="myFormRadio"> Radio 1
<input type="radio" name="myFormRadio"> Radio 2
<input type="radio" name="myFormRadio"> Radio 3
```